# 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcodebuild, react-native-ios

Here I'm using xcodebuild shell command to build a release version in my react native project, it comes a fatal error:

> 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found
>
> ```
> #import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
> ```

Xcode version: 8.3
react native version: 0.44.0

Any help ?

Comment: have you checked `RCTViewManager.h` is there or not?

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` should relink react to xcode.

Comment: also having this problem. How did you resolve?

Comment: anyone got solution. i am also facing same issue.

Comment: No solution. Shame, Apple.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5841629/ray  Thank you for comment. Its sorted my long standing issue.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me

1. Clear node_module folder and package-lock.json `rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json`
2. Clean Xcode's Build folder menu product>clean build folder
3. Reinstall dependencies and link `npm install && react-native link`
4. replace the `#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>` by `#import "RCTViewManager.h"`

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue in easy ways

uninstall react-native-linear gradient
cd ios && pod install

after uninstalling completely go to xcode.workspace =>product=>clean build

- run-ios

after successfully running

npm install react-native-linear-gradient
then cd ios && pod install

you must see autolinking for react-native-linear gradient

It will work properly

Note = Don't do manually linking if your react native version > 0.60